# .NET Core and .NET Framework 4.7 edit project option not available

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

When I create a `.NET Core 2.0 Project` I have to select both `.NET Core version (2.0)` and a `.NET Framework version (4.7)`.  But when I edit the project, I cannot change the `.NET Framework version`.  Why is that?  I am trying to use the function `app.UseRewriter(options);` and it is unavailable so I am theorizing that I have the wrong .NET Framework

---

I guess I just needed this package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite -Version 2.0.1
```

[image: Create Project]

[image: Edit Project]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's a confusing GUI. That got me mad as well (like some other stuff in Visual Studio if you are used to Jetbrains-IDEs).

You have chosen an ASP.NET **Core** Web Application as project type. So the only target frameworks that are being offered to you are .NET Core 1.0, 1.1 and 2.0 (in case you have installed 2.0, like you did).

Chose Web -> ASP.NET Web Application (**.NET Framework**) to get what you want.